# Gaussian pulse generator block issue

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

i'm new in Simulink and I'm using interpreted MATLAB function block to create a gaussian pulse generator.

This is the function:

```
 function y=mono_gauss(t)

   fs=20E9;                      %sample rate-10 times the highest frequency
   ts=1/fs;                      %sample period
   t1=.5E-9;                     %pulse width(0.5 nanoseconds)
   x=(t/t1).*(t/t1);             %x=(t^2/t1^2)(square of (t/t1);
   A=1; 
   y=(A*(t/t1)-ts).*exp(-x);     %first derivative of Gaussian pulsefunction

   end
```

The problem is that the output of the block generate only one pulse and my objective is  to generate a train of pulses just like a pulse generator block.
Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely better off designing your pulse in MATLAB, then using the [Repeating Sequence](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/repeatingsequence.html) to use it in Simulink.

For instance, in MATLAB

```
t = 0:0.01:1;
y = normpdf(t,0.5,0.05);
plot(t,y)
```

[image: Gaussian pulse]

Then within Simulink,

[image: Simulink Model]

I have also changed the step size of the model Solver to be 0.01.

You'll need to play around with various of these parameters to get the exact curve you desire.